# What is the difference between recursion and iteration in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

I've been given implement a particular algorithm in MIPS assembly, and said algorithm happens to have two possible implementations - recursive and iterative. Our prof explicitly stated, that our implementation should be recursive (not because it's better, it's just relevant to the material we covered).

My problem is that I don't quite understand the difference between a recursive procedure and an iterative procedure at this kind of level. Both loops and recursion are implemented (as far as I know) using jumps - you jump back to the start of the procedure until you reach some sort of base case. My prof is currently unavailable, so I am asking you people for help - what do you need to do in order to make your procedure recursive and not iterative? When does jumping back to the top of a procedure count as iteration, and when does it count as recursion?

Comment: Surely a function call (recursive or not) does more than just `jump` to the function in question?

Comment: You start learning something as difficult as assembly before learning recursion?

Comment: The question or recursion versus iteration is independent of language.

Comment: C.R. Yes, I know what recursion is, but only in high level languages.

I was confused with assembly because a function call is essentially a jump to a different place in the code, executing that bit and then jumping back. And if you want to be able to call functions within functions, you need to push the return address onto the stack at the start and then pop it when jumping back. So the problem is when you have a recursive function that calls itself, since a function call is essentially a jump, you end up jumping back to the top of the function, which resembles a loop quite a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the iterative version will just loop, while the recursive version will call itself, thereby building up a "chain" of calls which are finally reduced to produce the result of the function.

Let's say that you're doing a recursive calculation of 3! (3 factorial). The process would look something like this:

```
fact(3) => return fact(2) * 3
   fact(2) => return fact(1) * 2
      fact(1) => This is the base case; return 1
   return 1 * 2 (== 2)
return 2 * 3 ( == 6)
```

Here are a couple of reference implementations of an interative and recursive factorial function in MIPS assembly. Note that I used n==0 as the base case instead of n==1, since that's easier to do with the instructions available on MIPS.

```
# Iterative n!
# In: $a0 = n
# Out: $v0 = n!
fact_iter:
  li $v0,1
_fact_iter_loop:
  beq   $a0,$zero,_fact_iter_return
  multu $v0,$a0
  mflo $v0
  addiu $a0,$a0,-1
  j _fact_iter_loop
_fact_iter_return:
  jr $ra


# Recursive n!
# In: $a0 = n
# Out: $v0 = n!
fact_recur:
    addiu $sp,$sp,-4    
    sw $ra,($sp)         # Save the current return address on the stack
    beq $a0,$zero,_fact_recur_base_case
    addiu $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $a0,($sp)         # Save the current argument (n) on the stack
    addiu $a0,$a0,-1
    jal fact_recur     # Call the function recursively with n-1 as the argument
    lw $a0,($sp)         # Restore the saved argument
    addiu $sp,$sp,4
    multu $v0,$a0       
    mflo $v0            # Set $v0 = n * (n-1)!
_fact_recur_return: 
    lw $ra,($sp)       # Restore the return address
    addiu $sp,$sp,4
    jr $ra
_fact_recur_base_case:
    li $v0,1
    j _fact_recur_return
```